# AngularJS limitTo: 4 counts element which shouldn't be displayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, filtering

I have a problem with my filters. I have a JSON data and I want to show on my site 4 filtered elements. It looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="place in places | limitTo: 4 | filter: {cheap: 'true'}" class="col-lg-3">
```

So, I want to display only element when it has "cheap = true". My problem is that first element from JSON has "cheap = false" and my ng-repeat shows only 3 items instead of 4. I think it counts from the beginning of data and ends on 4 element, so if element 1 cheap is false it shows only next 3 which are true.

How can I make something like "if element 1 cheap is false, skip it and show next 4 elements, which are true".

I hope you understand what I mean. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried putting the `limitTo` after the `filter`? so like `<div ng-repeat="place in places | filter: {cheap: 'true'} | limitTo: 4" class="col-lg-3">`

Comment: You limit the result to 4, then filter those 4, returning a subset. Try to reverse the order of `limitTo` and `filter`, if that's possible.

Comment: Wow, it was so easy. It's correct answer thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place the `limitTo` after the `filter`

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.places = [{
    cheap: true
  }, {
    cheap: true
  }, {
    cheap: false
  }, {
    cheap: true
  }, {
    cheap: true
  }, {
    cheap: true
  }, {
    cheap: true
  }, ]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h1>Good</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="place in places  | filter: {cheap: 'true'} | limitTo: 4" class="col-lg-3">
      {{place.cheap}}
    </div>

    <h1>Bad</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="place in places| limitTo: 4  | filter: {cheap: 'true'} " class="col-lg-3">
      {{place.cheap}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to solution from comments, it was so easy - I had to switch order and place "filter:" in first place, than "limitTo:". Thank you!